# Convert column fields to multiple columns and rearrange data in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dataframe.

```
df1

Load           Instance_name            counter_name         counter_value
0              A                         bytes_read            0
0              A                         bytes_written         90
0              A                         last_time             100
0              A                         locks                 90

1              A                         bytes_read            10
1              A                         bytes_written         940
1              A                         last_time             1100
1              A                         locks                 910

2              A                         bytes_read            11
2              A                         bytes_written         910
2              A                         last_time             1100
2              A                         locks                 9120
```

***Loads can range upto 1000 - 10000 etc, and instance_name,counter_name is same across different loads, but can have different counter values. To simplify view, I need something like below ex. transform counter_name column fields to columns and rearrange data.***

```
df2 = 
Load     bytes_read     bytes_written   last_time  locks
0        0                    90          100       90
1        10                   940         1100      910
2        11                   910         1100      9120
```

I am new to python dataframe libraries and not sure the right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a straight forward pivot:

```
df2 = df.pivot( index = 'Load', columns = 'counter_name', values = 'counter_value')
```

giving

```
counter_name  bytes_read  bytes_written  last_time  locks
Load                                                     
0                      0             90        100     90
1                     10            940       1100    910
2                     11            910       1100   9120
```

Comment: As a follow up , How do we get the above view if there are multiple instances_names for each 'Load' ??

Comment: You can use the same pivot approach but with `index = ['Load', 'Instance_name']`. Basically you choose the pivot options to suit the required arrangement. Pandas also has [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) which allows more flexibility, including using an aggregating function.